Ошибка "Media_group" в telebot
Всё проверил, имя файла формируется корректно, и он находится по этому конкретному пути. Из-за чего возникает ошибка?
Ошибка:
  File "C:\Users\qwe\Desktop\leomatchbot\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 195, in _check_result 
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json) 
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: failed to send message #1 with the error message "EXTERNAL_URL_INVALID""

Код:
def show_profile(self, message, profile_info): 
    print(profile_info) 
    media = json.loads(profile_info[6]) 
    file_format = media[0] 
    print(1) 
    if profile_info[5] is None: 
        formated_string = f'{profile_info[4]}, {profile_info[1]}, {profile_info[3]}' 
    else: 
        formated_string = f'{profile_info[4]}, {profile_info[1]}, {profile_info[3]} – {profile_info[5]}' 
    print(2) 
    if file_format == 'PHOTO': 
        print(media[1]) 
        photo_group = [types.InputMediaPhoto(f'media/{media[1]}', caption=formated_string)] 
        if len(media) > 2: 
            for photo in media[2:-1]: 
                print(photo) 
                photo_group.append(types.InputMediaPhoto(f'media/{photo}')) 
       self.bot .send_media_group(message.chat.id, photo_group) 
        print(3) 
    elif file_format == 'VIDEO': 
       self.bot .send_video(message.chat.id, media[1], caption=formated_string)


Соберите минимально воспроизводимый пример, который без лишнего кода воспроизводит вашу проблему и обновите вопрос.

photo_group = [types.InputMediaPhoto(type='photo', f'media/{media[1]}', caption=formated_string)] 

попробуйте так
